# android eclipse installation error

Tags: eclipse

When I tried to update the ADT on My eclipse getting the following Error.

Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.

```
 Software being installed: Android Traceview 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
    Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Android Traceview 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 20.0.0.v201206242043-391819)
    To: org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (epp.package.jee 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [1.3.1.20100916-1202]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Java EE IDE Feature 1.3.1.20100916-1202 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 1.3.1.20100916-1202)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100909-9gF78GrkFqw7GrsZnvz0JWNTeb6fue6896L)
    To: org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse RCP 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T (org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group 3.6.1.r361_v20100827-9OArFLdFjY-ThSQXmKvKz0_T)
    To: org.eclipse.ui [3.6.1.M20100826-1330]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the message:

Only one of the following can be installed at once:

- Eclipse UI 3.6.1.M20100826-1330 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.1.M20100826-1330)
- Eclipse UI 3.6.2.M20110203-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2.M20110203-1100)
- Eclipse UI 3.6.0.I20100603-1100 (org.eclipse.ui 3.6.0.I20100603-1100)

It's producing a conflict because you have 
Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers   1.3.1.20100916-1202 installed, and it will likely contain a different UI version than Traceview uses.

Comment: @ Wijnand Wieskamp can u suggest me a solution to remove these confilects.

Comment: It sounds like you need to uninstall some of these parts to remove the conflict.

Comment: Yeah, I have no experience with this error but this is as far I could help. I can imagine that one of these 2 uses an out-dated version, so try updating you eclipse first and install the latest traceview maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Please use a new Eclipse installation. Yours is 2 years old, according to its 3.6.2 version number. Recent versions are [3.8 and 4.2](http://eclipse.org/downloads/). While the ADT *should* also work on older Eclipse versions, you are more on the safe side with a newer version. Besides all the new features you also get from the JDT, when developing for Android.

Answer (score 0):

You should update your installation of Eclipse before trying to install the Android plug-in.